# Separation of variables properly

Tags: calculus

So i have this differential equation of:

$\frac{dy}{dt} = ky(1-y)$

I'm just asking would this be the correct way to separate the like variables so i may integrate? I would get this.

*Multiplying both sides by $dt$ and dividing both sides by $y(1-y)$* Leaves me with

$\frac{dy}{y(1-y)} = k dt$

Would this be the correct way? Am i doing my basic algebra right? And after this i would integrate both sides but i know how to do that.

Comment: You can try a partial fraction decomposition on the left part :)

Comment: Yes, you put all the $y$'s on one side with the $dy$ (if this is possible, which it is in this case) and all the $t$'s on the other side with the $dt$ (here there is only the constant $k$),

Comment: @Jennifer That sounds like a good idea thanks for the advice.